# Handling click events from CellTable, how to handle them back to default dispatcher?

Tags: gwt, event-handling, celltable

I have a CellTable with one custom column where I render it manually and put a FlowPanel with a bunch of HTMLPanel/Anchor/FlowPanel widgets, and among them is DecoratorPanel.

DecoratorPanel renders as a table, of course.

Rendering happens like this:

```
public class MyExpandableCell extends AbstractCell<String> {
    ...
    @Override
    public void render(com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context, String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
        if (value != null) {
            FlowPanel fp = createDetailsFlowPanel(value);
            sb.appendHtmlConstant(fp.getElement().getString());
        }
    }
```

Now, I have added a handler for click events to my main CellTable. In my handler I traverse the tree to find a first TR belonging to my CellTable, by checking if it contains "even row" or "odd row" CSS classes.

However, when click happens inside of the DecoratorPanel (which is inside of my cell table's TD), my handler also gets triggered, since the click belongs to the cell table area.

I can detect this my seeing that parent TR does not have CellTable CSS classes.

QUESTION: how can I return processing of such click events to the DecoratorPanel - where it really belongs to? As it is now, my DecoratorPanel does not expand and I think because my click handler intercepts and suppresses all clicks on the CellTable level.

```
table = setupMyCellTable(PAGE_SIZE, CLIENT_BUNDLE, myCellTableResources);
mydataprovider.addDataDisplay(table);
table.sinkEvents(Event.ONCLICK);
table.addDomHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent e) {
        boolean isClick = "click".equals(e.getNativeEvent().getType());
        if (isClick) {
            Element originalElement = e.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget().cast();
            Element element = originalElement;
            String ctTrClassEven = CLIENT_BUNDLE.mainCss().cellTableEvenRow();
            String ctTrClassEven = CLIENT_BUNDLE.mainCss().cellTableOddRow();

            // Looking for closest parent TR which has one
            // of the two row class names (for this cellTable):
            while (element != null
                    && !"tr".equalsIgnoreCase(element.getTagName())
                    && !(element.getClassName().contains(ctTrClassEven) ||
                         element.getClassName().contains(ctTrClassEven))) {
                element = element.getParentElement();
            }
            if (element != null) {
                if (element.getClassName().contains(ctTrClassEven)
                        || element.getClassName().contains(ctTrClassEven)) {
                    // Found cell table's TR. Set new TR height.
                } else {
                    // Found TR from DecoratorPanel inside of the celltable's cell.
                    // Do nothing. But how do I make sure
                    // that decorator panel processes this click and expands?
                    return;
                    // Did not work: NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE javascript exception.
                    // if (originalElement != null) {
                    //     originalElement.dispatchEvent(e.getNativeEvent());
                    // }
                }
            } else {
                debugStr.setText("(did not find tr)");
            }
        }
    }
}, ClickEvent.getType());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug in GWT, triggered because decorator panel uses table to render itself:
http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5714
(another example http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6750)

Fix is expected to be shipped with GWT 2.5.